# Error response : RESPMSG = WEBSITE is invalid. This can contain alphabets with numerics only. can not contain special characters

Tags: android, android-studio, paytm

i am trying to implement paytm gateway in my application , have downloaded it's SDK and have go through it's documentation as described here :-

http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=how-to-use-apis

i have created sand-box account too and got MID from paytm , i am also attaching screen-shot of my MID

My parms is :--

```
 PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();

        //Kindly create complete Map and checksum on your server side and then put it here in paramMap.
        Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paramMap.put("MID", "DIY12386817555501617");
        paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", "DIY12386817555501617TestMerchant000111007");
        paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "DIY12386817555501617.aggarwal@paytm.com");
        paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
        paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
        paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1");
        paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "DIYtestingwap");
        paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL", "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp");
        paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH", "w2QDRMgp1/BNdEnJEAPCIOmNgQvsi+BhpqijfM9KvFfRiPmGSt3Ddzw+oTaGCLneJwxFFq5mqTMwJXdQE2EzK4px2xruDqKZjHupz9yXev4=");
        PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);
```

[image]
i goggled a-lot but have not found anything usefull , please let me know what exactly causing problem.

**Same question is here** :- https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit/issues/18 
**but not answered yet**.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Thanks

Comment: Little late but aren't you missing `REQUEST_TYPE` parameter? also use `TreeMap` and not `HashMap` because the order matters.